# Como usar o Format: Webgrid?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Estou desenvolvendo com o MVC, e tenho a view Listar

[...]

```
var columns = new WebGridColumn[] {
        grid.Column("Id"),
        grid.Column("Descricao"),
        grid.Column("UsuarioModificacao"),
        grid.Column("DataModificacao"),
        grid.Column("UltimoLogAcesso.DataAcesso"),
        grid.Column("UltimoLogAcesso.Ip"),
        grid.Column("UrlChamadaAlerta", format: (grid) => string.Format("{Id}")),
        grid.Column("FlagBloqueioPainel"),
        grid.ButtonColumn("ico_permission.gif", x => Url.Action("ConfirmarExclusao", "PainelChamada", new { id = x.Id } ), updateTargetId: "console"),
```

Preciso formatar a coluna UrlChamadaAlerta que deve ficar neste formato

```
painel.ejis.com.br/?id=<PainelChamada.ID>&token=<PainelChamada.GuidPainelChamada >
```

vou usar o `ID` e o `Guid` que estão no modelo PainelChamada

```
        public int Id {get; set;}
        public System.Guid Guid { get; set; }
```

Pessoal, o certo seria criar rotas, mas por enquanto o format vai atender o meu próposito.
Obs.: como será usado o format certas propriedades que seriam feitas com as rotas nao precisam ficar perfeitas.
Meu Format está errado, mas minha dificuldade é montar a expressão correta.

```
grid.Column("UrlChamadaAlerta",
            format: dataItem =>
                    string.Format("painel.ejis.com.br?id={0}&token={1}",
                                  dataItem.Id,
                                  dataItem.Guid),
```

Fica a dica pra quem precisar!

Comment: Essa classe `WebGridColumn` pertence a qual pacote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
grid.Column("UrlChamadaAlerta",
            format: dataItem =>
                    string.Format("painel.ejis.com.br?id={0}&token={1}",
                                  dataItem.Id,
                                  dataItem.Guid),
```

Fica a dica pra quem precisar!

Comment: Qual a diferença desse código com o que está na pergunta?

Comment: A resposta na pergunta o Cigano editou e acrescentou-a.

Comment: Thamires dê aceite na resposta por favor senão a pergunta vai ficar em aberta.